# Prisma update many to many relationship

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I am building a car marketplace backend with NestJS Prisma, and PostgreSQL as database. I'm trying to figure out how to update the join table in many-to-many relationships between car_listing and equipment when the car_listing table is being updated.

Here is the Prisma schema with models (tables):

```
model CarListing {
  id                    String   @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  email                 String
  year                  Int
  condition             String
  description           String

  equipment     ListingEquipment[]

  @@map("car_listing")
  @@schema("vehicle")
}

model Equipment {
  id               Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String
  type             String?
  safety           Boolean

  listings ListingEquipment[]

  @@map("equipment")
  @@schema("vehicle")
}

model ListingEquipment {
  carListing   CarListing @relation(fields: [carListingId], references: [id])
  carListingId String     @map("car_listing_id") @db.Uuid
  equipment    Equipment  @relation(fields: [equipmentId], references: [id])
  equipmentId  Int        @map("equipment_id")

  @@id([carListingId, equipmentId])
  @@map("listing_equipment")
  @@schema("vehicle")
}
```

And here is the code where I tried something after following guidelines from Prisma documentation but I am still not able to resolve it:

```
  async updateListing(
    id: string,
    updateCarDto: UpdateCarListingDto,
  ): Promise<CarListingEntity> {
    const { equipment, ...dto } = updateCarDto;

    return this.prisma.carListing.update({
      where: {
        id,
      },
      data: {
        ...dto,
        equipment: {
          connectOrCreate: equipment.map((equipmentId) => ({
            where: {
              equipmentId,
            },
            create: {
              equipmentId,
              carListingId: id,
            },
          })),
        },
      },
      include: {
        model: true,
        equipment: true,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Also, I would need to be able to delete relations from the join table if a client provides an equipment list that doesn't contain items from the previous list.

Thanks in advance!